# 'Module not found' babel error after installing axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, babeljs

I used `create-react-app` to set up a React project, then install `axios` in the same project folder.

In `App.js`, I imported and used `axios`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {users: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and got the following error:

```
./node_modules/axios/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/katietruong/Projects/read- 
it/client/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel- 
loader/lib/index.js' in '/Users/katietruong/Projects/read-it/client' 
.
```

How does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: maybe yarn or npm ci again it can fix problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of npm.

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

If that still doesn't work you could try removing node_modules and running npm install again

```
rm -Rf node_modules
npm install
```